# How to extract a number from a string in a dataframe and place it in a new column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(test = c("test_A_1_1.txt", "test_A_2_1.txt", "test_A_3_1.txt"), value = c(0.51, 0.52, 0.56))

          test   value
1 test_A_1_1.txt  0.51
2 test_A_2_1.txt  0.52
3 test_A_3_1.txt  0.56
```

**Expected output**

I would like to copy the numbers on the end of the string in column 1 and placed it in column three or four respectively, like this:

```
          test value  new new
1 test_A_1.txt  0.51   1  1
2 test_A_2.txt  0.52   2  1
3 test_A_3.txt  0.56   3  1
```

**Attempt**

Using the following code, I am able to extract the numbers from the string:

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract_all("test_A_3.txt", "[0-9]+")[[1]])[1] # Extracts the first number
as.numeric(str_extract_all("test_A_3.txt", "[0-9]+")[[1]])[2] # Extracts the second number
```

I would like to apply this code on all the values of the first column:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(new = as.numeric(str_extract_all(df$test, "[0-9]+")[[1]])[1])
```

However, this lead to a column `new`, with only the number `1`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here, you are extracting the first instance of numbers `[[1]][1]`?  In that case, just do `str_extract`

Comment: Based on a comment you left on an answer, you say you need to be able to extract multiple numbers per file name. That's an important test case that you should describe in your question and include in your example dataset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(new = readr::parse_number(as.character(test)))
```

---

Regarding the OP's issue, it is selecting only the first `list` element (`[[1]]`) from the `str_extract_all` (which returns a `list`).  Instead, it is better to use `str_extract` as we need to extract only the first instance of one or more digits (`\\d+`)

```
df %>%
    mutate(new = as.numeric(str_extract(test, "[0-9]+")))
```

If we need to get the output from `str_extract_all` (in case), `unlist` the `list` to a `vector` and then apply the `as.numeric` on that `vector`

```
df %>%
     mutate(new = as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(test, "[0-9]+"))))
```

If there are multiple instances, then keep it as a `list` after converting to `numeric` by looping through the `list` elements with `map`

```
df %>% 
     mutate(new = map(str_extract_all(test, "[0-9]+"), as.numeric))
```

NOTE: The `str_extract` based solution was first posted here.

---

In `base R`, we can use `regexpr`

```
df$new <- as.numeric(regmatches(df$test, regexpr("\\d+", df$test)))
```

#### Update

With the updated example, if we need to get two instances of numbers, the first one can be extracted with `str_extract` and the last (`stri_extract_last` - from `stringi` can be used as well), by providing a regex lookaround to check for digits followed by a `.` and 'txt'

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new1 = as.numeric(str_extract(test, "\\d+")),
      new2 = as.numeric(str_extract(test, "\\d+(?=\\.txt)")))
#            test value new1 new2
#1 test_A_1_1.txt  0.51    1    1
#2 test_A_2_1.txt  0.52    2    1
#3 test_A_3_1.txt  0.56    3    1
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use the `as.numeric(str_extract_all("test_A_3.txt", "[0-9]+")[[1]])[1]` format? In the actual data I have multiple numbers per string that I would like to extract...

Comment: @user213544  If there are multiple strings, it would be better to remain as a `list`

Comment: Based on the comment from @camille I updated the question a little bit. The actual files have name like `test_a_1_1.txt` and `test_a_2_1.txt`. If I use subsetting: `df1 %>% 
  mutate(new = map(str_extract_all(test, "[0-9]+"), as.numeric)[1])` the problem remains that all values are `1`, which I do not understand.

Answer (score 7):

Why not a base R solution?

```
df$new <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", df$test))

df
#          test value new
#1 test_A_1.txt  0.51   1
#2 test_A_2.txt  0.52   2
#3 test_A_3.txt  0.56   3
```

**Edit.**

Following the example in user @camille's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891167/how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-a-dataframe-in-r-and-place-it-in-a-new/56891738#56891738) where the strings may have different numbers of numbers, here is a solution using package `stringr`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(test = c("test_A_1.txt", "test_A_2.txt", "test_A_3.txt"), value = c(0.51, 0.52, 0.56))
df2 <- data.frame(test = c("test_A_1_1.txt", "test_A_2_1.txt", "test_A_3_1.txt"), value = c(0.51, 0.52, 0.56))
df3 <- data.frame(test = c("test_A_1_1.txt", "test_A_2_1.txt", "test_A_3_1.txt", "test_A_4_2_1.txt"), value = c(0.51, 0.52, 0.56, 2))

num2cols <- function(DF, col = "test"){
  s <- stringr::str_extract_all(DF[[col]], "[[:digit:]]+")
  Max <- max(sapply(s, length))
  new <- do.call(rbind, lapply(s, function(x){
    as.numeric(c(x, rep(NA, Max - length(x))))
  }))
  names_new <- paste0("new", seq.int(ncol(new)))
  setNames(cbind(DF, new), c(names(DF), names_new))
}

num2cols(df1)
num2cols(df2)
num2cols(df3)
```

Answer (score 6):

Slightly modifying your existing code:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new = as.integer(str_extract(test, "[0-9]+")))
```

Or simply

```
df$new <- as.integer(str_extract(df$test, "[0-9]+"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that they are fixed width, you can:

```
df$new <- substr(df$test, 8, 8) %>% as.integer
```

I recommend using `as.integer` rather than `as.numeric` because you are working with integers, not floats.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as you said you might have multiple numbers in a file name, I'd suggest using a method that is more verbose but would scale up to work for more than 1 or 2 numbers. That way, you aren't hard-coding columns like `new1` and `new2`. To illustrate, I added a third number to one of the file names.

The original problem you ran into was that `str_extract_all` returns a list, and you then need to extract items from that list. You can unnest that list to get individual rows for each number, add a key that sequences over each file name's numbers, then spread to a wide shape to get one column per number, with `NA` where no number exists in the file name.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(test = c("test_A_1_1.txt", "test_A_2_1.txt", "test_A_3_1.txt", "test_A_4_2_1.txt"), value = c(0.51, 0.52, 0.56, 2))

df %>%
  mutate(nums = str_extract_all(test, "\\d+")) %>% 
  unnest(nums) %>%
  group_by(test) %>%
  mutate(key = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key, value = nums, sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   test [4]
#>   test             value key1  key2  key3 
#>   <fct>            <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 test_A_1_1.txt    0.51 1     1     <NA> 
#> 2 test_A_2_1.txt    0.52 2     1     <NA> 
#> 3 test_A_3_1.txt    0.56 3     1     <NA> 
#> 4 test_A_4_2_1.txt  2    4     2     1
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `sub` or `stringi::stri_extract_last_regex`:

```r
sapply(df1, function(x) sub('.*(\\d{1}).*', '\\1', x))
```

or

```r
sapply(df1, function(x) stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(x, "\\d{1}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract a number from a string in a data frame and place in a new column.

```
t$new<-substr(t[,1] , 8,8)
    
          test    value  new 
1 test_A_1.txt     0.51   1  
2 test_A_2.txt     0.52   2  
3 test_A_3.txt     0.56   3
```